# Update Git repository of a jenkins jobs using rest

Tags: git, rest, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am taking job name,git repository,git username and password as input from the user.I am able to create a jenkins job using rest but I am not able to set that job's git repository path.So how to connect a jenkins job with a git repository using rest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use the workaround presented in "[How to create a job using the REST API and cURL](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/220857567-How-to-create-a-job-using-the-REST-API-and-cURL) "

First:

> **Create a job using the UI**. This job can be used to create a base config that can be used to create new jobs.
>
> To retrieve the job `config.xml` that you made via the UI, to use for creating new jobs:

```
curl -X GET http://developer:developer@localhost:8080/job/test/config.xml -o mylocalconfig.xml
```

> Obviously, replace:
>
> - developer:developer with your username:password
> - localhost:8080 with your Jenkins URL
> - test with the name of the job that you created via the UI

Then,

> use this config to create a new job:

```
curl -s -XPOST 'http://developer:developer@localhost:8080/createItem?name=yourJobName' --data-binary @mylocalconfig.xml -H "Content-Type:text/xml"
```

The idea is to:

- use `mylocalconfig.xml` (from step 1) as a template,
- change the content of `mylocalconfig.xml` with the right git repo path to use in Step 2 and create a job using the [Remote access API](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API).

Comment: Thanks for the help.I simply created a dummy xml file and have mentioned the git url in that.Now the project is directly created with the set path :)